# Status of replication support in ApacheDS?

Tags: ldap, replication, directory

The [features](http://directory.apache.org/apacheds/1.5/features.html) page indicates they're expecting to support multi-master replication "soon".  Does it have any basic master-slave replication yet or does it currently not support any form of replication?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The latest version 1.5.7 doesn't support replication. In SVN trunk we implemented RFC 4533 (https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4533) as replication protocol, which is also used by OpenLDAP. It will be available with ApacheDS 2.0. Please track the [mailing lists](http://directory.apache.org/community%26resources/mailing-lists-and-irc.html) to get informed when ApacheDS 2.0 will be released.

Comment: 2.0 shows a tab for replication but it still says coming soon as of 2/7/2012

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to this issue

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26543958/apacheds-multi-master-config
and associated link
http://joacim.breiler.com/apacheds/ch08s02.html